# maven deploy-file to local directory

Tags: maven, testing

I would like to deploy an artifact to a local directory to verify how maven will publish the artifact before setting up an external server. Ideally it publishes as close as possible and generates the correct metadata to the point that once pointing to the real server it works with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it by using the `deploy-file-mojo` plugin, for example:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
      -Durl=file:///Users/my-user/my-test \ # any folder you like to deploy to
      -DgeneratePom=true \
      -DupdateReleaseInfo=true \
      -DgroupId=com.company.product \
      -DartifactId=my-artifact \
      -Dfile=path/to/my/file.zip \
      -Dversion=0.0.1
```